# Getting Legacy Rails site up and running but having issues with dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2

I just inherited a rails site from a client and trying to get it up and running on my computer.  Running into constant errors about dependencies and ruby versions.  Is there a right way to go about this or is it just keep fiddling with the versions of gems until it all plays nice

Here is my list of gems i have in a file called GEM_LIST in site root:

```
actionmailer (2.2.2)
actionpack (2.2.2)
activemodel (3.0.9)
activerecord (2.2.2)
activeresource (2.2.2)
activesupport (3.0.9, 2.2.2)
arel (2.0.10)
builder (2.1.2)
capistrano (2.8.0)
chronic (0.6.2)
composite_primary_keys (2.2.2)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
highline (1.6.2)
hominid (3.0.2)
i18n (0.5.0)
mysql (2.8.1)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
rack (1.3.2)
rails (2.2.2)
rake (0.8.7)
rspec (1.3.2)
rspec-core (2.6.4)
rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
rspec-rails (1.3.2)
tzinfo (0.3.29)
will_paginate (2.3.16)
```

I tried installed each one individually and try to run ruby script/server and get this error

```
/home/#####/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:224:in `specification': undefined method `version_requirements=' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x7f4a3f884308> (NoMethodError)
```

Running ruby 1.8.7
Gem Version 1.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using gem -v1.3.5 with a rails 2.2.2 with no issues. Downgrade to that version should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You version of Rails is not compatible with that version of rubygems. Try an older version of rubygems, such as 1.3.1.